# check if double/float has more than 2 decimal number

Tags: java, android, double, numeric, bigdecimal

i want to make a check in my app. If the double entered by the user has more decimals throw a popup to the user.
Here is my code i tried many combinations but no one works

```
String bigStart = etVehicleMileageAtStartTour.getText().toString(),
      bigEnd = etVehicleMileageAtEndTour.getText().toString();
 if ((bigStart.indexOf(".") >= 0 && bigStart.indexOf(".") > bigStart.length() - 2)
 || (bigEnd.indexOf(".") >= 0 && bigEnd.indexOf(".") > bigEnd.length() - 2)) 

{
 // throw popup
}
```

I tried also to convert to big decimal and use scale method but it is not working

```
BigDecimal bigAtStart = BigDecimal.valueOf(vehiculeMileageAtStart);
BigDecimal bigAtEnd = BigDecimal.valueOf(vehiculeMileageAtEnd);
int i = bigAtEnd.scale();
int j = bigAtStart.scale();
if (bigAtEnd.scale() > 99 || bigAtStart.scale() > 99) {
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `etVehicleMileageAtStartTour.getText().toString()` actually return?

Comment: @SteveSmith it is returning decimal numbers. like "12.01"

Comment: Get the number of decimal places with something like `bigStart.split("\\.")[1].length()`.

Comment: @SteveSmith it works thanks man :D

Comment: In the BigDecimal version I would have compared `scale()` to 2, not 99.